# Use value defined in another json inside CMakePresets.json

Tags: json, cmake, cmake-presets

I need to define some properties in a .json file, that must be used inside a `CMakePresets.json`. This because the `CMakePresets.json` that I use in my pc is different from the one that I use in the build machine, but some properties (like library versions) are the same and I want to avoid to duplicate those information because I'll forgot to update both files.

So I've created a `CMakeCommon.json` file that contains:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 25,
    "patch": 1
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "cacheVariables": {
        "MYLIB_VERSION": "1_0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and my `CMakePresets.json` is:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 25,
    "patch": 1
  },
  "include": [
    "CMakeCommon.json"
  ],
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "displayName": "Default Config",
      "description": "Default config generator with ninja",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
      "hidden": true,
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "MyPath/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
        "VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET": "x64-windows",
        "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "TRUE",
        "MYLIB_PATH": "D:/MyLib/${MYLIB_VERSION}"
      },
      "environment": {
      }
    },
    {
      "inherits": "default",
      "name": "debug",
      "displayName": "Debug",
      "description": "Debug build.",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
      }
    },
    {
      "inherits": "default",
      "name": "release",
      "displayName": "Release",
      "description": "Release build.",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
      }
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "configurePreset": "debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "Release",
      "configurePreset": "release"
    }
  ],
  "testPresets": [ ]
}
```

I cannot use `MYLIB_VERSION` variable defined in `CMakeCommon.json` inside the cache variable `MYLIB_PATH` defined in `CMakePresets.json`.

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your current implementation: You need to give the preset in the `CMakeCommon.json` file a name, and then have the `default` preset in `CMakePresets.json` to inherit from it, otherwise how would the `default` preset know to use the value of `MYLIB_VERSION` from there.

The second issue is that `${MYLIB_VERSION}` in the `default` preset in `CMakePresets.json` is not a valid macro expansion. Currently, there is no way to access cache variables of presets you inherited from through macro expansion, only environment variables can be referenced. So you need to make `MYLIB_VERSION` an environment variable in `CMakeCommon.json` and then use `$env{MYLIB_VERSION}` instead of `${MYLIB_VERSION}`

All in all it would look something like this:

`CMakeCommon.json`:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 25,
    "patch": 1
  },
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "common",
      "hidden": true,
      "environment": {
        "MYLIB_VERSION": "1_0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`CMakePresets.json`:

```
{
  "version": 5,
  "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 25,
    "patch": 1
  },
  "include": [
    "CMakeCommon.json"
  ],
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "inherits": "common",
      "displayName": "Default Config",
      "description": "Default config generator with ninja",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build/${presetName}",
      "hidden": true,
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "MyPath/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
        "VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET": "x64-windows",
        "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "TRUE",
        "MYLIB_PATH": "D:/MyLib/$env{MYLIB_VERSION}"
      },
      "environment": {
      }
    },
    {
      "inherits": "default",
      "name": "debug",
      "displayName": "Debug",
      "description": "Debug build.",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
      }
    },
    {
      "inherits": "default",
      "name": "release",
      "displayName": "Release",
      "description": "Release build.",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
      }
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "configurePreset": "debug"
    },
    {
      "name": "Release",
      "configurePreset": "release"
    }
  ],
  "testPresets": [ ]
}
```

If you need `MYLIB_VERSION` to be a cache variable you can also add it back to the cache variables pf the `common` preset, but set the value to `$env{MYLIB_VERSION}` so you don't have to duplicate the version number.

I'd also like to point out that CMake actually has a built-in mechanism for this exact issue of needing machine-specific presets. If you rename your current `CMakePresets.json` file to `CMakeUserPresets.json` and the `CMakeCommon.json` file to `CMakePresets.json` then you can remove the `include` from the file that is now `CMakeUserPresets.json` and get the same behavior, but with the standard names.